# Jest client/ ElasticSearch cluster informations

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm using jest client in a java application to connect to an ElasticSearch cluster and now i want to find informations on how to get cluster informations like this with jest api:

```
{
"name" : "",
"cluster_name" : "",
"version" : {
"number" : "2.3.2",
"build_hash" : "",
"build_timestamp" : "",
"build_snapshot" : ,
"lucene_version" : "
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Is it that page curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty' ?

Comment: yes when runing ElasticSearch

Comment: i'm afraid you can't do this via jest/java api at all. Could you explain your usecase this information?

Comment: in fact i just wanted a java method to give me these informations

Comment: any luck with my answer?

Comment: it works perfect ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spent a little time in reading jest source code and get a result. Please look at the code below:

**Jest.java**

```
import io.searchbox.client.JestClient;
import io.searchbox.client.JestClientFactory;
import io.searchbox.client.JestResult;
import io.searchbox.client.config.HttpClientConfig;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Vladislav Kislyi <vladislav.kisliy@gmail.com>
 */
public class Jest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Construct a new Jest client according to configuration via factory
        JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
        factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig.Builder("http://localhost:9200")
                .multiThreaded(true)
                .build());
        JestClient client = factory.getObject();

        GetStartPage getStartPage = new GetStartPage.Builder().build();
        try {
            JestResult execute = client.execute(getStartPage);
            System.out.println("result =" + execute.getJsonString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Jest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

and **GetStartPage.java**

```
import io.searchbox.action.AbstractAction;
import io.searchbox.action.GenericResultAbstractAction;

public class GetStartPage extends GenericResultAbstractAction {

    protected GetStartPage(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        setURI(buildURI());
    }

    protected String buildURI() {
        return super.buildURI() + "/?pretty";
    }

    @Override
    public String getRestMethodName() {
        return "GET";
    }

    public static class Builder extends AbstractAction.Builder<GetStartPage, Builder> {

        @Override
        public GetStartPage build() {
            return new GetStartPage(this);
        }
    }
}
```

You get in console exactly what you wanted